# How do I prevent a user from entering duplicate objects into ArrayList Java?

Tags: java

So I am Attempting to prevent a user from entering a duplicate entry (object) based on one examining the first element they enter.  I've tried several methods and it keeps walking right over me.  Any suggestions on how to stop this? Also, note the indentation here isn't represented correctly.  That is not the case in the program itself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Inventory {
private ArrayList<Book> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void addBook() { //open method addBook
    System.out.print("Enter the book id number: ");
    int id = scan.nextInt();
    if (inventory.contains(id) == true){
        System.out.print("This book is already in the inventory!");
        id--;
    } 
    else if (inventory.contains(id) == false) {
        
        System.out.print("Enter book title: ");
        scan.next();
        String title = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter book price: ");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();
        inventory.add(new Book(id, title, price));
    }
} //Close method addBook
```

Comment: Use `Set` instead of `ArrayList` to prevent duplications.

Comment: I think Hashtable or Map is better for this, you can check the key if it's already exist. Right now your code won't work because checking for id won't be equal to the actual object. Oh, you also don't need to check twice, after the first if, the else part is guaranteed to run when there's no duplicate (assuming you already move to hashtable or map)

Comment: @Martheen It can be achieved using `Set`, just need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Book` class. No external checks will be required then after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are unwilling to use `Set`, then you must loop through the elements of the ArrayList to check if it contains the book or not. It's because your ArraList contains `Book`s not `int` of their id's. So the condition `inventory.contains(id)` will always return false.

You can do something like this:

```
        int id = scan.nextInt();
        for (Book book : inventory) {
            if(book.id == id){
                //print duplicate and return
            }
        }
        //add the book and return
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was definitely attempting to work around the hash set option.  Not because I dislike the HashSet, but I am trying to make this work without it.  This worked beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

## `Set`

To prevent duplicates you can use [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) instead of `ArrayList`. The [`Set#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) method returns `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element.

If you also want to preserve the order of your elements you might want to check out `LinkedHashSet`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-vs-treeset-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to other answers:

```
if (inventory.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getId() == id))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of using LinkedHashSet provided by Shivansh Narayan seems just right. One other method you could use is using HashSet to check the IDs and ArrayList to store your books.
Also, the *else if* condition is redundant.

```
public class Inventory {
private ArrayList<Book> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private HashSet<Integer> bookIDs = new HashSet<Integer>(); // a set to store all unique book IDs
public void addBook() { //open method addBook
  System.out.print("Enter the book id number: ");
  int id = scan.nextInt();
  if (bookIDs.contains(id)){
      System.out.print("This book is already in the inventory!");
      id--;
  } 
  else{
    
    System.out.print("Enter book title: ");
    scan.next();
    String title = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter book price: ");
    double price = scan.nextDouble();
    inventory.add(new Book(id, title, price));
    // don't forget to add the id to the set
    bookIDs.add(id);
 }
} //Close method addBook
```